# Convert react JSX object to HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application that generates HTML output based on some configuration. Like this:

```
export const getHtml = (config) => {
  const {classes, children} = config
  return (<div className={classes.join(' ')}>{children}</div>);
}
```

Inside the react app I can easily display the resulting DOM objects, but I want to save the HTML code to DB, to display it on a different page (without loading react/parsing the config again)

I could not find a way to convert the JSX object to plain HTML...

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the [`renderToStaticMarkup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) method. As per the documentation:

> You can use this method to generate HTML on the *server* and send the markup down on the initial request for faster page loads and to allow search engines to crawl your pages for SEO purposes.

```
const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
);
```

Comment: is not render `onError` at `img` tag btw, any solution ?

Comment: Thank you a lot for `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` method it's definitely what I was looking for!

Comment: JS and hooks won't work inside static markup.

Answer (score 17):

**redux code**:

Here is the full code that I had to use in my react/redux application.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

...

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    ...

    getHtml(config) {
        const {classes, children} = config
        return ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            <Provider store={this.context.store}>
                <ChildComponent classes={classes}>{children}</ChildComponent>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

ParentComponent.contextTypes = { store: React.PropTypes.object };
```

Notes:

- Use `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()` to get the HTML code
- Specify `ParentComponent.contextTypes` to make this.context.store available
- Need to wrap the ChildComponent in a `Provider` so it has access to the redux store.

Comment: How would you do it with MobX?

Comment: @Philipp Is there a way to have interactive markup which can dispatch actions with `renderToString`?

Comment: is there a way to do it without redux?