# How to convert React element to dom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create an HTML element and provide it to some third-party component.

```
const testElement = <div ref='myself' className='test-label'>Hello (React) HTML element!</div>
thirdParty.addElement(testElement)
```

In the above I create the element with React, but passing it on as said raises an error, obviously because it's a React element and not a native DOM element.

**Is there a way to convert `testElement` to a DOM element?**

That said, I'm looking for a solution that will **retain event handlers etc'** associated with the component, so simply converting to HTML (`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(testElement)`) doesn't cut it.

-

Edit regarding duplicate:

The other one discusses about the HTML string. I need the object along with its event handlers etc'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert react JSX object to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308011/convert-react-jsx-object-to-html)

Comment: Thanks for the time, but I emphasized "retain event handlers etc'". The one you refer to converts to HTML net. So it is not a duplicate.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense. Wrong approach. Why don't you explain your problem so we can help find a better solution?

Comment: @CharlieBrown my use case: google maps AdvancedMarkerElement (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/graphic-markers) needs a DOM element as content. Would be nice to have some proxy from the memoized JSX React Element. No luck with Refs yet. Only working solution yet is to render to a static markup (HTML) and set with innerHTML to a memoized div element. But since it replaces the content every time - all the remote (url) images flicker (reloaded by browser)

Answer (score 3):

Try (`ReactDOM.render(textElement, thirdParty)`)
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render