# React.js - converting JSX to raw HTML string

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I am currently thinking about making a CMS project and one of the features I want to add is making a HTML page by clicking on buttons then storing that HTML in a JSON, of course in a string format. The way I want to make this is pretty easy, on a certain button click it adds the JSX element and renders it real time so the user says what he is building. Lets say the user then has to click a button that will save that page to the json. Is there any way I can convert JSX elements to a raw HTML string so I can save it to json or do I manually have to keep on adding to a string when making JSX elements and create the raw HTML myself?

Comment: [renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)?

Comment: @rayhatfield That may just do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308011/convert-react-jsx-object-to-html